# Use pam_exec to run a script on an ssh login event

Tags: ssh, pam, alpine

I'm trying out linuxserver.io openssh-server. Its a lightweight openssh image and makes it easy to configure with public key and user name.

If I run it, ssh with public key auth, works as expected:

```
$ docker run --rm -d --name ac1 -e PUBLIC_KEY -e USER_NAME=dough lscr.io/linuxserver/openssh-server:latest
```

Now I want to use pam_exec to run a script on an ssh login event.

Interactively, in the `ac1` container, I enable PAM in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```bash
...
UsePAM yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
...
```

and restart openssh server:

```bash
# s6-svc -r /run/service/openssh-server
```

But upon ssh from the host machine, the server appears to accept key authentication, but promptly closes the connection before starting a shell session:

```bash
$ ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/mykey -p 2222 dough@172.18.0.3

debug1: Server accepts key: /home/dough/.ssh/mykey RSA SHA256:tUHJFPJXyGdhe2poOnpbgDz1t6mhvpmSiRprMIJdFko explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:tUHJFPJXyGdhe2poOnpbgDz1t6mhvpmSiRprMIJdFko
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:tUHJFPJXyGdhe2poOnpbgDz1t6mhvpmSiRprMIJdFko
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection closed by 172.18.0.3 port 2222
```

On `ac1`, in `/config/logs/openssh/current`, it seems there's a problem with pam account management: **"Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info"**:

```
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821095711  debug1: /config/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: matching key found: RSA SHA256:tUHJFPJXyGdhe2poOnpbgDz1t6mhvpmSiRprMIJdFkoM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821106309  debug1: /config/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwardingM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821110668  Accepted key RSA SHA256:tUHJFPJXyGdhe2poOnpbgDz1t6mhvpmSiRprMIJdFko found at /config/.ssh/authorized_keys:1M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821117354  debug1: restore_uid: (unprivileged)M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821121394  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication: RSA key is allowedM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821133896  debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 23M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821202231  debug3: mm_sshkey_verify: entering [preauth]M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821204241  debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 24 [preauth]M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821208932  debug3: mm_request_receive: enteringM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821215539  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 24M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821295607  debug3: mm_answer_keyverify: publickey RSA signature verifiedM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821300496  debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication optionsM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821302447  debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 25M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821310562  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 102M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.821312128  debug3: mm_request_receive: enteringM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.826582283  debug1: do_pam_account: calledM
2022-09-22 02:16:41.826587001  debug2: do_pam_account: auth information in SSH_AUTH_INFO_0M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.831312509  debug3: PAM: do_pam_account pam_acct_mgmt = 9 (Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info)M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.831316748  debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 103M
2022-09-22 02:16:41.831321867  Failed publickey for dough from 172.18.0.1 port 40700 ssh2: RSA SHA256:tUHJFPJXyGdhe2poOnpbgDz1t6mhvpmSiRprMIJdFkoM
```

I've tried creating a minimal `/etc/pam.d/sshd.pam` with:

```
account include base-account
```

but no joy. Whether this file exists or not, the behaviour is the same.

Need some help here...

I'm stuck with the pam configuration to run pam_exec.

But the goal is to to run a hook script on an ssh login event. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments, here's what I learned...

1. Launch openssh server container with `PASSWORD_ACCESS=true`.
2. Enable PAM in `sshd_config`.
3. Configure PAM to run a hook script when an ssh session opens.
4. If the hook script needs container environment variables, use `#!/usr/bin/with-contenv bash` in the shebang line.

You can run a hook script on ssh login with password authentication. For publickey authentication, its also possible, but you'll need to consider the security implications for your context.

Setting `PASSWORD_ACCESS` to true, enables read only permission on `/etc/shadow` for the chosen user's group. That ownership change happens on
[this line](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-openssh-server/blob/88be1491057fb76d3f8294bd9010b28c5546e135/root/etc/cont-init.d/50-config#L44) of the init script. This fixes the PAM account failure "Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info" because PAM is able to read `/etc/shadow`.

This also has the side-effect of enabling password authn which we likely don't want when we use publickey authn.